# why is fluendo playback kit not detected

Tags: sound, video, media, playback, fluendo

I needed to play several media formats.  mp3,mpg (video and audio), flv, avi, any and all media files so I installed the fluendo complete kit and yet ubuntu 14 still on some of my files wants to install from multiverse.

i paid for fluendo as a legal alternative but i am considering just returning to windows as just to be able to listen to music I legitimately  paid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install,

## [Ubuntu restricted extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/)

This package consists of almost all the codecs you need. It can be installed through Ubuntu Software Center.

Alternatively, open up your Terminal and execute the command below:

> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

---

As another option, you can install [VLC media player](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/vlc/) to decode the media.